# Extend Grid.Mvc Annotations with ressource file as header source

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, annotations, grid.mvc

I'm working the the **Grid.Mvc Framework** to present my Model Data.

Look at: [Source Code](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GridMvc/GridMvc/DataAnnotations/GridAnnotaionsProvider.cs) and [Documentation](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Data%20annotations&referringTitle=Documentation)

Out of the box there are two options to present column headers

First:

Without ressource file..

```
//Annotation
[GridColumn(Title = "Active Foo?")]
public bool Enabled { get; set; }


[GridColumn(Title = "Date", Format = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime FooDate { get; set; }
```

...

```
//Display the Model items with assigned Column Titles
@Html.Grid(Model).AutoGenerateColumns()
```

Second:

Use Ressource Strings in View..

```
//Assign Column Header from 
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
        columns.Add(n => n.Enabled).Titled(DisplayFieldNames.Enabled); 
        columns.Add(n => n.FooDate).Titled(DisplayFieldNames.FooDate);
})
```

---

I want to know how I can extend the First Method (using Data Annotation in Model)

Something like:

```
[GridColumn(Title ="Enabled", ResourceType = typeof(DisplayFieldNames))]
```

and

```
[GridColumn(Title = "Date", ResourceType = typeof(DisplayFieldNames), Format = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```

The **ResourceType** Attribute inside should make the Grid look for the Column Title inside my Ressource File "DisplayFieldNames"

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution with the support of a friend.

Here it is, hopefully it is helpful for others too.

```
public class LocalizedGridCoulmnAttribute : GridColumnAttribute
{

    private Type _resourceType;

    /// <summary>
    /// The type of the Ressource file 
    /// </summary>
    public Type ResourceType
    {
        get
        {
            return this._resourceType;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._resourceType != value)
            {
                ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(value);
                string someString = rm.GetString(LocalizedTitle);

                this._resourceType = value ?? value;
            }
            if (ResourceType != null && LocalizedTitle != String.Empty)
            {
                ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(ResourceType);
                Title = rm.GetString(LocalizedTitle);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Overrides The Title Property of GridColumnAttribute
    /// Works with Ressourcefile
    /// </summary>
    public string LocalizedTitle
    {
        set {
            if (ResourceType != null && value != String.Empty)
            {
                ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(ResourceType);
                Title = rm.GetString(value);
            }
            else Title = value ?? value;
        }
        get { return Title; }
    }
}
```